What is the logical fallacy that goes like « If this person were X, then event Y would not have happened »
this is my first question, so I hope I’ve done things correctly.
I’ve been observing political discussions, and one sort of argument that I believe to be fallacious appears as in the title.
It seems to come from a prejudiced attitude against Xs. Here is an example:

A Christian pastor gets arrested for preaching at a pro-abortion demonstration.
Someone comments; « if they were a Muslim, they would not have been arrested! »

I am not sure what logical fallacy this would be? I am thinking that it could be an example of a « false premise » that comes from the person’s biases. Also a red herring? It seems to be fairly common from what I have seen, so I’m interested in identifying it so I can potentially refute statements that have it.
Thanks!

It's a Cause/effect fallacy. Often called a false-cause fallacy.  They are assuming ( without justification) that the reason the person was arrested, was because of their religeon. If they wanted to improve their argument, they would have to try and justify such an assumption.

You cannot refute invalid arguments by labeling them with some name. You might merely succeed in "proving" that you're a smartass, leading to your argument being dismissed. You have to be able to explain what's wrong with the argument. In this example some implicit analogy is made and there is an implicit claim that the pastor was arrested for being a Christian, which seems obviously false. There also seems to be an implicit premisse that the authorities are discriminating against Christians, which is generally an absurd claim too (depending on where you are in the world).

In an actual situation it may also not be wise or effective to try to directly refute this kind of bigotry and stereotyping (unless you're talking to family of close friends), but use a more Socratic method by simply asking "Oh? Is that so? Have you witnessed something like this? How do you know?" Let them refute themselves with their own words.

Simplified "If 'X', then not 'Y happens'" means "'Y' cannot happen if 'X'". Mathematically it's "(not X) or (not Y)", so it's true whenever "not Y", independent of X. Essentially you can make conclusions from X to Y, but not from Y to X, right?

Not every assertion is an argument, and not every mistaken assertion results from a logical fallacy. Logic is truth-preserving, so when incorrectly applied it can produce false conclusions from true premises (i.e. when the argument is a fallacy). Far more commonly, correct logic is applied from false premises. If someone takes as a premise that Muslims do not get arrested, then the argument is logically sound, just the premise is ridiculous.

@mudskipper I agree with your comment, with the very minor nitpick that it is not obviously false that someone was arrested for being a Christian. There have been times and places where that was enough by itself to be arrested for. For that matter, that applies to most religions. There have been times being of almost any given religion was adequate reason to be arrested.

@TimothyAWiseman - Yes - of course (that's also why I added "depending on where your are in the world").

I don't see how such a statement is rooted in a "prejudiced attitude against Xs". The statement is about a third party having different standards for X and Z (which may or may not be true). A commonly seen version is "They [person of colour] would not have been stopped by the police, had they been white".

I suggest there is no logical fallacy that goes anything like your Question, because which the entire exposition adds nothing useful.

That's not an argument: it is a counterfactual conditional. It is a conditional statement typically of the form, "if A were the case then B would be the case", or, "if A had been the case then B would have been the case".
Such conditionals are often difficult to evaluate, depending on how far removed the antecedent is from what is actually true, and also depending on whether we have a reliable theory that might allow us to infer the consequent from the antecedent.
In the case you mention, it would be appropriate to enquire what data there is to support such a claim. Have other pastors been arrested for the same thing? Have muslims been arrested or not arrested for something comparable? Does this vary by jurisdiction? Have the arresting officers given reasons for making the arrests? Without such data, the claim is simply baseless. But if plenty of data is available, then there may be grounds for saying that the law is being applied inconsistently.

Simply stating the conclusion is not a logical fallacy. What brings them to that conclusion is where the fallacy would lie.
The most obvious candidate fallacies in the example you gave are faulty or hasty generalization and stereotyping.
There may of course be other fallacies at play, but since you haven't laid out an argument, we could only guess.

Pointing out a perceived double standard is in itself not a logical fallacy.
The allegation might be true (if Christians are indeed more often persecuted than Muslims for the same behavior) or it might be false (if they are not). But the factual truthfulness of the accusation has nothing to do with whether the accusation is a fallacy or not.

Usually in deductive reasoning your first premise is some sort of general rule, your second premise is some application of the rule and the conclusion is the result of that application.
So if the rule is correct and you're correct to apply it, then the predicted result should be correct as well. If that is theoretically the case then it's valid, while if these things actually are correct then it's sound. Usually in the real world that's more complicated as things are rarely "true" or "false" but rather "likely" or "unlikely" so even though lots of statements are technically fallacious (as their conclusion doesn't HAVE TO follow from the premises, but you could for example come up with really more or less bonkers counter examples), but nonetheless hold most of the time, so might still be a good heuristics and a strong argument despite not holding in ALL cases.
Now this statement: "If this person were X, then event Y would not have happened"
Leaves a lot open. Not only is it a counterfactual as Bumble already explained, so not really looking at a real example but a fictional one, it also leaves out a lot of information required to evaluate.
I mean the implied accusation seems to be something akin to
 P1: Rules ought to apply universally
 P2: But if A does it the result is X, while if B does it the result is Y
 C: Therefore rules don't apply universally (and that's a bad thing)".

So you're accusing an institution that is supposed to be impartial of some sort of bias.
Now there are a multitude of outcomes for that:

Sure the person could be right and there is discrimination happening
They could be mistaken as to what the rule actually is. So idk if an insurance advertises with "free glasses" that might not mean that everyone gets glasses, but that they provide coverage for those who get a doctors prescription for glasses.
They might be mistaken about the universality of the rule. So it might not apply to all, but just to a large number of people and X might be a legit counter example where a more specific rule overrides the more general.
Also in some situations a universal rule could be flawed due to very specialized conditions (so the implied part in the conclusion might also be wrong)

And so on. So whether that is a fallacy, correct, misleading or whatnot depends on the specifics of the case. So just from the statement alone you can't tell if it's fallacious beyond the point that it's an incomplete argument.

Calm down y'all; it's a simple non-sequitur.
Absent an accompanying syllogism, there is no argument to be fallacious.

Neither your title nor the example in the body of your question is a fallacy, although they may be fallacious.
Named fallacies as common arguments that are known to be false - they don’t lead to valid conclusions.
Your usage is too vague to be common and in so much as they may be used, they may be true.
Your usage in the title is generally made as a statement about leadership and power — a claim that if a specific someone had been in charge or involved in a specific incident a different outcome would happened.  This claim is generally an acclamation or condemnation of the character or abilities of someone. You might think this makes it an Ad Hominem, it’s not because that is exactly what is being debated.  No named fallacy here.
The example in your body is not even an argument, it’s a comment from the peanut gallery. If it was made as part of an argument, you might think it was an appeal to ignorance. But we can’t say what its truth-value would be, without more context, and that context would presumably provide evidence. It could as easily be true as false.  So, no named fallacy here either.

What's the logical fallacy that goes like, "If this person were X, then event Y would not have happened"?
As suggested by the answers and comments already submitted, there is a lot wrong with this reasoning, as common as it is.
I am going to say this statement is a species of ad hominem argument. In ad hominem arguments, something is said to be false (typically) because of some bad personal quality of the speaker (e.g., a conviction for theft), not for the poor quality of the argument itself.
Here, the falsehood or overgeneralization is some belief about X, or about a group that X is a member of.

I wonder: Is it the same category as (someone wanting X, and another one wants him to do Y) "if I don't get X, I won't do Y" - It says nothing what will happen if he "gets X".

This isn't an ad hominem argument, because from the statement about person X, nothing is concluded about the validity of any claim made by person X.

@kaya3. Here, the unspoken assumption is that Person X would claim that their group is treated the same as any other. Opponents would claim that defense is untenable, given the claimant’s membership in the group.

The question is about a commenter and a pastor. In the question, the commenter makes some statement about the pastor, but this statement is not related to any claim made by the pastor. In fact, the question doesn't refer to any claim made by the pastor. If I understand correctly, your analysis is based on the implicaiton that the pastor would have claimed to be treated equally to Muslims, if only somebody had thought to ask him. I don't see how that claim is at all implied, but either way even if such a claim is implied, it's not what the question is about.

To be clear, if the pastor had said "as a Christian I am treated by the police equally to a Muslim" and the commenter said "if he were a Muslim he would not have been arrested", that still wouldn't be argument ad hominem. Argument ad hominem would be if the commenter said something like, "the pastor is wrong about that, because he is a Christian" or "the pastor is wrong about that, because he is not a Muslim".
